# Limit number of requests per minute using Supertest

Tags: javascript, typescript, supertest, web-api-testing

We're using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) with `Typescript` to test out APIs.
For some of them (e.g. user registration, change password, etc) an email address is sent that is required for confirmation (user confirm token, reset password token, etc).

In order to achieve this, we decided to use [GuerillaMail](https://www.guerrillamail.com/), as it's a simple disposable email client with API. After doing the prerequisites (setting the email using their email), the following piece of code does its job in a couple of cases:

```
private async getEmailId(sid_token: string, emailType: EmailType): Promise<string> {
        var mail;
        var mailToken = this.getSidToken(sid_token);

        //Keep trying until the email gets in the inbox
        // Infinite loop is prevented by the jest framework timeout
        while (!mail) {
            const result = await request(this.guerillaMailApiUrl)
                .get('')
                .query({
                    f: 'check_email',
                    seq: 0,
                    sid_token: mailToken
                });
            if (result.body.list != undefined) {
                mail = result.body.list.filter(m => m.mail_subject == emailType && m.mail_from == 'email@domain.com' && m.mail_read == 0)[0];
            }
            else {
                mail = undefined;
            }
        }
        return mail.mail_id;
    }
```

However, it comes with a limitation of 20 requests per minute, limitation that is causing tests to fail.

Is there a way to limit the number of request made?

**LATER EDIT:**
I made it work by creating a delay:

```
async delay(ms: number) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
```

and calling it right before exiting the `while` loop:

```
await this.delay(5000);
```

Is there a cleaner/nicer/efficient/performant/etc way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

This one rate limiter that I used in my past projects **Bottleneck** https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  maxConcurrent: 20,
  minTime: 60000
});

while (!mail) {
  // set limiter here
  const result = await limiter.schedule(() => request(this.guerillaMailApiUrl)
    .get('')
    .query({
      f: 'check_email',
      seq: 0,
      sid_token: mailToken
    }));
  if (result.body.list != undefined) {
    mail = result.body.list.filter(m => m.mail_subject == emailType && m.mail_from == 'email@domain.com' && m.mail_read == 0)[0];
  } else {
    mail = undefined;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps